# Constraints for overridden generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to understand how constraints (on class or generic methods) can affect the methods themselves. Take this code for example:

```
class Base<T> where T:class, IComparable<T>
{
    public virtual void Method(T obj) { }
}

class Derived<T> : Base<T> where T:class, IComparable<T>, IEnumerable<T>
{
    public override void Method(T obj) { }
}
```

This code compiles fine and the compiler/runtime is able to resolve polymorphic calls to the non-generic method 'Method' which takes a parameter that is of generic type. In the base class and the derived class, the constraints on the type parameter are different.

I have also specified a class constraint to keep out value types which may probably cause a problem because a different class is generated for each value-type instantiation while only one such class is instantiated for reference types.

On the other hand, the following code does not compile.

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Method<T>() where T : class, IComparable<T> { }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Method<T>() where T : class, IComparable<T>, IEnumerable<T> { }
}
```

The language specification for C# says that the constraints on a generic method are carried over as it is to an overriding method and that it is illegal to specify any constraints as such. I did some searching for it on Google and found out that this is disallowed because of the complexities associated with supporting polymorphic calls (with respect to maintaining a method table and so on). But I still don't understand why it works in Case 1 above which is similar to this except that it is the class which is generic. How is the compiler/runtime able to do it in Case 1 while Case 2 is flagged as a compiler error?

Comment: case 1 you have base class and dervied both generic

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - so? in the first case, it is the class which is generic while in the second case it is the method. doesn't specifying a 'class constraint' restrict the instantiations to only one? so why is one not allowed while the other works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just consider the question "why is it illegal to add a constraint onto a generic method in a virtual override?" Because that is really straightforward.

```
class Foo : IComparable<Foo> { ... }
...
Base b = new Derived();
b.Method<Foo>();
```

First off, should this be illegal?  Yes.  Calling `b.Method<Foo>` actually calls `Derived.Method<Foo>`, but `Foo` does not meet the contraints.  So this must be illegal.

On which line of code should the error be reported?  The declaration of `Foo` is legal.  The conversion of `Derived` to `Base` is legal.  From the compiler's perspective, the call to `b.Method<Foo>` is legal; `b` is of type `Base` and `Foo` meets the constraints for `Base.Method`.  So the error cannot be reported on any of those lines. The only place to report the error is on the line in `Base.Method` that has the `where` clause that causes the problem. Therefore that kind of `where` clause must be illegal, to prevent anyone from ever writing the otherwise-legal program fragment above.

Now what about your first case, where the class is generic?  Well, how would you get a `Base<Foo>` in that scenario?  Certainly not from an instance of `Derived<Foo>`, because you can't even make that type in the first place!  The equivalent problem program is:

```
Base<Foo> b = new Derived<Foo>();
b.Method();
```

Now where should the error be reported? Clearly it can be reported on the line that creates the `Derived<Foo>`! So there is no need to make the additional `where` clause illegal.

Answer (score 4):

In case 1, the method can be used for any object of type T, when T is determined by the class. For any particular class, there is only one type T, so overriding is simple. The fact that you can use a wider set of types T to generate Base<T> than to generate Derived<T> is no problem.

In case 2, the methods can be called for any number of types. However, the types that are allowed in the Derived class are only a subset of the types allowed in Base class, which means you have a "partial override", which makes things a mess.